# Accepted research paper but not online

Tags: publications, research-process

Some of my research paper accepted in maths journals and it will take almost one year to be appear online in journal site. I want to use these paper for academic purposes like interview. How to use these . I am not having even vol no.,  Issue no.,  pages no. or DOI etc  in journal. Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: If it's fully accepted, you can list such papers in your CV like other papers, and where you usually mention the journal your paper is in, you say "forthcoming in (name of journal)."

Comment: @gnometorule      but I want to show it in interviews. And what is the meaning of fully accurate. Recently mail is for acceptance and in journal site it’s shows accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can share your work in a limited way with individuals, so this should have no effect on applications or interviews. Even after you give up copyright to your work, it is typical to get back a limited license for sharing. This will vary with publishers.

And, fair use would also, typically, permit sharing for such purposes as it isn't really "republishing", nor does it diminish the value of the copyright to the holder enough to warrant a complaint.

You can, in (poorly defined) limited circles, share your work, indicating that it is to appear in a specific journal. Just send a copy, indicating that it is not for redistribution.